# How to bind F1-F12 key as keyboard macro in Emacs?

Tags: function, emacs, macros, key

I want to bind F1-F12 key as keyboard macro. Starting kbd-macro with Shift-[F1-F12] and execute it with [F1-F12]. Each key can have different macro. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to record a keyboard macro when you press shift-F1, which is saved into F1 and executed when you press F1?

Comment: Yes. And each function keys have its own kbd-macro.

Comment: Surely, when you assign 12, you'll forget what each of them does sooner or later.
Use `name-last-kbd-macro`. You can then call it with `M-x`. With `smex` it's painless.

Comment: Thanks abo-abo. Probably I will use two or three. So I won't forget. Naming, saving, executing with macro-name will take a several time for me . I want to cache kbd-macro within function keys. I admit this title is overstatement.

Answer (score 2):

Try this bit of code:

```
(mapc (lambda(x) (global-set-key x 'auto-name-macro))
      '([f5] [f6] [f7] [f8]))

(defun auto-name-macro (arg)
  (interactive "p")
  (if defining-kbd-macro
      (progn
        (kmacro-end-or-call-macro arg)
        (fset
         (intern (format "mcr-%s" last-command-event))
         last-kbd-macro))
    (execute-kbd-macro
     (intern
      (format "mcr-%s" last-command-event)))))
```

You start macro definitions with <kbd>f3</kbd> as before, but now
<kbd>f5</kbd>, <kbd>f6</kbd>, <kbd>f7</kbd> and <kbd>f8</kbd> function in the same
way as <kbd>f4</kbd>, except each remembers their own macro.
You finish definition with the key and then call it again with the same key. Exactly like <kbd>f4</kbd>.
Macros also get names, e.g. `mcr-f5`, `mcr-f6`, ..., so you can call them with <kbd>M-x</kbd> instead.

### UPD: macros can reference each-other and be bound to any key

There's more than a few lines of code so I've put it at https://github.com/abo-abo/centimacro.
The setup is just

```
(require 'centimacro)
```

<kbd>f5</kbd> will call `centi-assign`.

1. It prompts you where you'd like your next binding to be, so you press <kbd>f6</kbd>,
   for instance.
2. The macro is now recording, and pressing <kbd>f6</kbd> will stop it and assign
   the new macro to <kbd>f6</kbd>.
3. Now you can use what you defined in <kbd>f6</kbd> for other macro, say <kbd>f7</kbd>, but it could be <kbd>C-e</kbd>, it's not restricted to functional keys.

Here's an example:

```
<f5><f6>foo<f6>                 ;; Now <f6> inserts "foo".
<f5><f7><f6>bar<f7>             ;; Now <f7> inserts "foobar".
<f5><f8><f6>-<f7>-<f6><f8>      ;; Now <f8> inserts "foo-foobar-foo".
<f5><f6>omg<f6>                 ;; Now <f6> inserts "omg",
                                ;;     <f7> - "omgbar",
                                ;;     <f8> - "omgbar-omg-omg".
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It almost solves my question. BTW can I use kbd-macro during difining kbd-macro? When I am difining f6 kbd-macro, can I use pre-defined f5 kbd-macro?

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't be possible as long as there are no circular dependencies.
I'll try to update the code tomorrow to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Well assigning a macro to a key is trivial. Just record it as usual, then type:

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>

I'd also suggest that you don't want to waste 12 useful bindings on "record a macro" when one (pre-existing) binding will do, so you may prefer to adapt to this approach rather than pursuing the original request.

Lastly, note that <kbd>F5</kbd>-<kbd>F9</kbd> are all reserved for the end user, but other function keys are not, and already have useful bindings (including keys for recording keyboard macros, funnily enough), so I would focus on those. (If you're running out, you can always make one or more of them a prefix binding.)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know the command. It's very useful and simple.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can do this exctly as you specified, because any function you write to help with this has to have (start-kbd-macro) as the last call in it - that's the way that start-kbd-macro works.  This prevents it from naming the keyboard macro after the user finishes recording it.

The only way I can see to make something similar would be to have shift-F1 be the key that you use after you *finish* recording the macro that is to be stored in F1.

The user would have to start recording a kbd macro the usual way, but hit shift F1 after he completes it.  You could then easily put a function on shift-F1 that renames the macro to the function that you have bound to F1.

The code would be something like this:

```
(defun assign-macro-to-f1 () (interactive)
  (name-last-kbd-macro 'f1-kbd-macro)  
  (global-set-key[(f1)] (execute-kbd-macro `f1-kbd-macro))
)  

(global-set-key [(shift f1)] `assign-macro-to-f1)
```

(note - I tried also ending the kbd macro in the shift-f1 function, but it seems like messing around with kbd macros in functions is problematic ... better to let them record the macro the normal way, and save it with this function)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I have used:

After recording the macro, name it using <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>.

Then you can use <kbd>M-x</kbd>`insert-kbd-macro` and give it the name of the macro you just defined. That will insert some lisp code which defines the macro. You can then put the generated lisp code in your `init.el` file, followed by a `global-set-key` to set the macro to whatever key you want.

Here's a sample of the generated lisp and keybinding (the macro just enters the word "test"):

```
(fset 'test-macro
(lambda (&optional arg) "Keyboard macro." (interactive "p") 
  (kmacro-exec-ring-item (quote ([116 101 115 116 41 backspace] 0 "%d")) arg)))
(global-set-key '[(f5)] 'test-macro)
```